# pgfplots: "number too big" while plotting

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to plot a parameterized function:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\def\pa{1.0*10^-8};
\def\pb{9.3*10^-8};
\def\pc{1.92};
\def\pd{4052};
\def\pe{0.000318};

\begin{axis}
[xmin=0, xmax=60000
,ymin=0,ymax=150
,scaled x ticks=base 10:-3]

    \addplot [
    ,domain=0:60000
    ,restrict y to domain=0:150] 
    {
        (900*\pc + 30*\pe*pi*x + \pb*pi^2*x^2) / (30*\pa*\pd*pi*x)
    }; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Unfortunately, I get the message "Number too big", and I can't seem to find a solution.

I'm not sure how to use `\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}` in this case and whether it is going to help at all.

How can I configure pgfplots to actually plot my function?

Comment: Can you reduce the number of *everything* (domain, numbers, etc.)? It seems that TikZ cannot parse such big numbers.

Comment: Do you mean reducing the x range by a factor of 1000 and adopting the parameters?

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with big numbers. i mean if you could work with lowest numbers, such that `\def\pa{1.0*10^-4};` or something like that. It was an idea, do not put it into practice and read the excellent answers!

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to TeX.SE! It helps to divide the numerator and denominator by `\pa` since then there won't be the product `\pa*\pb` any more.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\def\pa{1.0*10^-8};
\def\pb{9.3*10^-8};
\def\pc{1.92};
\def\pd{4052};
\def\pe{0.000318};

\begin{axis}
[xmin=0, xmax=60000
,ymin=0,ymax=150
,scaled x ticks=base 10:-3]

    \addplot [
    ,domain=0:60000
    ,restrict y to domain=0:150] 
    {
        (900*(\pc/\pa) + 30*(\pe/\pa)*pi*x + (\pb/\pa)*pi^2*x^2) / (30*\pd*pi*x)
    }; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that `(900*\pc + 30*\pe*pi*x + \pb*pi^2*x^2) / (30*\pa*\pd*pi*x)` is not equal to `(900*(\pc/\pa) + 30*(\pe/\pa)*pi*x + (\pb/\pa)*pi^2*x^2) / (30*\pd*pi*x)` but I am sure that you keep the same formula. Are they equal?

Comment: @manooooh I divide both numerator and denominator by `\pa`, why should that not be valid? Or is there a typo?

Comment: Forgot that, your expressions are indeed the same!